# VBA: Left and bottom align 2 shapes, then delete the shape in thebackground

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am searching for a way to perform the following operation on two shapes that are selected in powerpoint.

1. Take the shape in the foreground (i.e. the shape that is more in the front) of the two shapes and left and bottom align it with the one that is in the background.

**2. Delete the shape in the background.**

What I have got so far is the operation for the bottom and left align which looks as follows:

```
Sub LeftandBottom_Align()

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, False
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignBottoms, False

End Sub
```

**How do i get the delete-part done?**

A little bit of basic explanation would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the rearmost shape like so:

```
Dim oBackShape As Shape


With ActiveWindow.Selection

    ' Get a reference to the rearmost of the two selected shapes
    ' so you can use it later to delete the shape
    If .ShapeRange(1).ZOrderPosition > .ShapeRange(2).ZOrderPosition Then
        Set oBackShape = .ShapeRange(2)
    Else
        Set oBackShape = .ShapeRange(1)
    End If

    ' Align the shapes
    ' .Align may not always work the way you'd expect it to
    ' so if not, ask
    .ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, False
    .ShapeRange.Align msoAlignBottoms, False


End With

    ' Delete the rearmost shape
    oBackShape.Delete
```

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks a bunch. This exactly does what I want it to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shapes ZOrderPosition Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa216042%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to determine which shape is in the background

```
Sub LeftandBottom_Align()

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, False
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignBottoms, False

Dim i As Integer
i = 2 'Assuming two shapes

 While i >= 1
 With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i)

    If (.ZOrderPosition = 1) Then
        .Delete
        Exit Sub
    End If

 i = i - 1

 End With
 Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work unless you happen to have selected the first two shapes on the slide; .ZOrderPosition gives you the "stacking" order on the slide, not within the selected ShapeRange. For example, draw five shapes on the slide, select the last two you drew and run the code; nothing gets deleted.

Comment: May be, But the question is specifically about two selected shapes!

Comment: Two selected shapes.  Yes.  Not necessarily the first two shapes on the slide, though.